# How would I replicate graphs like the following in Core Plot?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-plot

I would like to use the Core Plot framework to produce a graph that looks like the following:

[image]

Additionally, I would like to provide charts within a table view like the following:

[image]

How would I set up charts like these using Core Plot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Install CorePlot SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859002/how-to-install-coreplot-sdk)

Comment: @Justin: I have mentioned my specific requirements (Screenshots). So this cannot be considered as a possible duplicate.

Comment: i agree with your point. i attempted to undo the vote, but it was not possible. sorry about that.

Comment: @Justin : Anyways mate!! that is ok. it is more important that you accepted your mistake and I really appreciate you for that :)

Comment: Given that installation of Core Plot is handled in the linked question, I've removed that part of the question and focused it on what's new here: replicating the style of these particular charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is easy--it's just a scatter plot with a gradient fill. The examples included with the framework show how to do this.

See this thread on the Core Plot discussion board for ideas on how to approach the second problem: http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss/browse_thread/thread/00344ef4e0234a51

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/w/list

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link for installing core-plot.
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-core-plot-in-an-iphone-application. Also read the comments section in the above link for some changes.