# How to Install CorePlot SDK

Tags: iphone, charts, core-plot

I want to create a chart application. I read that CorePlot can be used to do this, but I don't know where may I go to download the CorePlotSDK, and how or where to install it. I also read the procedure for installing the CorePlotSDK but I'm not clear about that.

Please explain the downloading and installing procedure.

Also explain the frameworks that I want to include and that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

The project is hosted [here](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot). Follow the instructions there to download it, then maybe tell us any issues you have after that, or what questions you have integrating it with your project.